# Ubuntu 20.04 icon resize issue

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

hello guys how to resize the Ubuntu icon in desktop? its so big for me I try to search on google but all the tutorial not work please help me thank you did someone try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Desktop icons in Ubuntu 20.04 are provided by a Gnome Shell extension. Some sizes can be set using the preferences.

To access these preferences, install "Tweaks" ("Gnome Tweaks"). On the Extensions tab, find "Desktop Icons" on the Extensions tab, and click the button with a cog wheel to access the settings.